# How to prefer mobile connection over proxy?

Tags: windows-7, networking, browser, proxy, internet-connection

I have win7.
I have proxy connection and also mobile connection via my Android phone(via USB port).
I want to connect to internet only via mobile connection so I specified no Proxy in my browser (Mozilla), but connection is not very stable and I very often get message from proxy that I cannot display it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The no-proxy setting does not affect, which network device firefox uses for connections. The network device is selected by windows network manager (generalized name). Using a proxy will just add one additional server to the route from your computer to the target server. Best way to use a mobile network, is to disable other network devices. (Unplug ethernet and turn off WLAN)

You can also edit network device priorities in advanced network settings:

1. Click the Start Button
2. Right Click "Network" and then left Click Properties
3. From the "Network And Sharing Center" window click "Change Adapter Settings"
4. On the "Network Connections" window, press the ALT key on your keyboard to being up the menu bar
5. Click the "Advanced" menu and then "Advanced Settings"
6. In the "Advanced Settings" window you will see the "Adapters and Bindings" tab and under "Connections" you will see the order they are in, you can use the arrows to the side to move the connection priority up and down.

[image: Advanced network settings]

Comment: Problem is I want to use one browser(IE) for proxy, and another(mozzila) for mobile connection, therefore I can not prioritize. With No Proxy set, it is working, but after some time it stops. Could be something with USB going to sleep, since my phone connected via USB.